# Find the index of the 'first' non-zero element in a padded vector of signed integers in C++

Tags: c++, vector, integer, zero, signed

I have a zero-padded vector of signed integers:

```
[1, 5, 2, 7, 4, 8, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want:

```
[1, 5, 2, 7, 4, 8, 0, 0, 1].
```

Similarly to how a binary number is padded with zeros on the left side,

```
100 == 000000100 == 00000000000100 == ...
```

My vector works the same:

```
[1, 5, 2, 7, 4, 8, 0, 0, 1] == [1, 5, 2, 7, 4, 8, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] == ...
```

It's possible that my vector may contain zeros.

However, if you start at the end of the vector and check until you reach a non zero value, you can find where the last 'actual' value of my vector should be.

---

Any suggestions on how to do this more efficiently than looping through the vector from the end?

> Note: the length will always be greater than `2 ^ 9 (512)`, but may get as large as `2 ^ 13 (8192)`.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your use case? Could you just store the index of the leftmost nonzero value? Is there any reason why you're storing so many extra zeros?

Comment: So if you have `n` where it is where your vector should end then what is stopping you from creating a new vector of size `n + 1` and copy `0 to n` from the original vector?

Comment: I have a value, call it n, that dictates how long my vector must be to account for overflow (regarding assorted operations that will be performed on the vector). The vector is sent to **size(n)** _extremely early on_ in the program and this is the final output.

Comment: I wouldn't even store the extra zeros. I'd store a *value* that says *how many* zero pads there are, and only keep the `n` actual significant digits. I.e. a struct with members for `std::vector` of digits, and a `uint16_t` that holds the zero-pad count.

Comment: I'm looking to convert this vector of signed integers into a decimal, assuming an extended binary format in Big Endian. However, I don't want to account for, say, 2^300 to 2^512 if I'm only multiplying them by 0s.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz, the OP's question was "Any suggestions on how to do this more efficiently than looping through the vector from the end?" -- how is using a reverse iterator any different than that?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid looping through the vector from the end.  How else is std::vector going to find the first non-zero from the end if not looping through them?  It doesn't keep track of that kind of thing, so the only way to bypass this is to track it outside of std::vector.

Comment: @MichaelRodby, _Doh!_ Comment removed. Didn't read far enough... :-(